# Changing .htaccess in wordpress file gives an internal server error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, internal-server-error

So i'm working with the wpmudev snapshot plugin which gives an 'max_execution_time' warning (30 is to low), when I update this to 180 by adding

```
php_value max_execution_time 180
```

to the .htaccess file (wp root) my site gives an internal server error. Is there an reason why this happens? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Contact your Hosting Company and update your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct and refer below scenario,

1. Check with your error log and if it is a PHP error try to troubleshoot that.
2. what is your server engine, because Apache engine only have .htaccess file others like nginx not support .htaccess file
3. If not got solution check with your hosting before that make sure your site not have an issue.